# mdadm RAID - Reboot during grow - reshape is not resuming

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm

I am on Debian 10, a fresh install from a week ago.
I moved my array from a previous server, everything went fine.

I then added a new drive in the array and did a grow.

```
mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sda2
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --raid-devices=5
```

But sadly I forgot a reshape was in progress and I did a clean shutdown of the server.

At the restart the raid is showing as "State : clean" but it is not resuming the reshape.
The array Size should obviously be at 8000GB (2TB x4) if the reshape was completed instead of 6000GB.
And the line "Delta Devices" is also still showing.
So something is odd.

```
    # mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Feb  1 20:36:04 2017
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 5860113408 (5588.64 GiB 6000.76 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953371136 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 5
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Jan  9 02:28:28 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 5
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

     Delta Devices : 1, (4->5)

              Name : Debbie-NAS:1  (local to host Debbie-NAS)
              UUID : d1915c3c:c727e641:060346f9:a4f590ac
            Events : 18828

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      130        0      active sync   /dev/sdi2
       1       8      146        1      active sync   /dev/sdj2
       3       8       98        2      active sync   /dev/sdg2
       4       8      114        3      active sync   /dev/sdh2
       5       8        2        4      active sync   /dev/sda2
```

I tried to resume manually the reshape but it did nothing:

```
# mdadm --grow --continue /dev/md1 --raid-devices=5
```

Output from mdadm --examine:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[ijgha]2
/dev/sda2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : d1915c3c:c727e641:060346f9:a4f590ac
           Name : Debbie-NAS:1  (local to host Debbie-NAS)
  Creation Time : Wed Feb  1 20:36:04 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906745344 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
     Array Size : 7813484544 (7451.52 GiB 8001.01 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906742272 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
    Data Offset : 259072 sectors
     New Offset : 254976 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 43eed232:f3d1d806:02e8bb5c:e1c90318

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 2651604992 (2528.77 GiB 2715.24 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (4->5)

    Update Time : Sat Jan  9 02:28:28 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 23eaf33b - correct
         Events : 18828

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdg2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : d1915c3c:c727e641:060346f9:a4f590ac
           Name : Debbie-NAS:1  (local to host Debbie-NAS)
  Creation Time : Wed Feb  1 20:36:04 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906745344 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
     Array Size : 7813484544 (7451.52 GiB 8001.01 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906742272 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
    Data Offset : 259072 sectors
     New Offset : 254976 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 2d31b7f3:57b1d12f:ba0d9e73:3cb36b33

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 2651604992 (2528.77 GiB 2715.24 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (4->5)

    Update Time : Sat Jan  9 02:28:28 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 401224d3 - correct
         Events : 18828

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdh2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : d1915c3c:c727e641:060346f9:a4f590ac
           Name : Debbie-NAS:1  (local to host Debbie-NAS)
  Creation Time : Wed Feb  1 20:36:04 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906745344 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
     Array Size : 7813484544 (7451.52 GiB 8001.01 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906742272 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
    Data Offset : 259072 sectors
     New Offset : 254976 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 017bea40:0a6ce8e3:f4a5639e:97a33826

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 2651604992 (2528.77 GiB 2715.24 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (4->5)

    Update Time : Sat Jan  9 02:28:28 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 5eeeb1f0 - correct
         Events : 18828

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdi2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : d1915c3c:c727e641:060346f9:a4f590ac
           Name : Debbie-NAS:1  (local to host Debbie-NAS)
  Creation Time : Wed Feb  1 20:36:04 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906745344 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
     Array Size : 7813484544 (7451.52 GiB 8001.01 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906742272 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
    Data Offset : 259072 sectors
     New Offset : 254976 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 31b13e8c:ede4a229:8da4c45c:d7c1814d

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 2651604992 (2528.77 GiB 2715.24 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (4->5)

    Update Time : Sat Jan  9 02:28:28 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : d5a77dd7 - correct
         Events : 18828

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdj2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x45
     Array UUID : d1915c3c:c727e641:060346f9:a4f590ac
           Name : Debbie-NAS:1  (local to host Debbie-NAS)
  Creation Time : Wed Feb  1 20:36:04 2017
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 5

 Avail Dev Size : 3906745344 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
     Array Size : 7813484544 (7451.52 GiB 8001.01 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906742272 (1862.88 GiB 2000.25 GB)
    Data Offset : 259072 sectors
     New Offset : 254976 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3d5bc161:4f1b1a23:e16f3630:57fcee88

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
  Reshape pos'n : 2651604992 (2528.77 GiB 2715.24 GB)
  Delta Devices : 1 (4->5)

    Update Time : Sat Jan  9 02:28:28 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : b380641a - correct
         Events : 18828

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

But it looks like the array is read-only for some reason, maybe it is blocking the reshape ?

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
    Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
    md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdi2[0] sdh2[4] sdj2[1] sdg2[3] sda2[5]
          5860113408 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
          bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

The underlying filesystem is correctly mounted and I can access my data.

But something must be wrong somewhere because the array does not have the size it should have and the reshape was not completed.
But I don't know how to fix it.

Maybe I can try to start a "check"?

```
echo 'check' > /sys/block/md1/md/sync_action
```

But I am affraid it can break something if the reshape is not complete.

Any idea ?

Comment: /proc/mdstat? dmesg? kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did the following command that started back the reshape:

```
mdadm --readwrite /dev/md1

cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md1 : active raid5 sdi2[0] sdh2[4] sdj2[1] sdg2[3] sda2[5]
      5860113408 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
      [======>..............]  reshape = 33.9% (662920160/1953371136) finish=6817.6min speed=3152K/sec
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

So it looks like everything is fine.
I will let the reshape finish before shutting the server down this time

Comment: see `man md`, `/sys/module/md_mod/parameters/start_ro` regarding this behavior of auto-read-only mode.